# Lightbox2 for bootstrap not working on Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on bootrap framwork and i use Lightbox2 for my gallery part.The strange part ismy gallery works well on Google Chrome,but doesnt work well on Firefox and Internet Explorer.It shows the big image rather than the thumbnail.Can any one help me out.
Heres my website gallery
http://hihschool.pancakeapps.com/gallery.htm
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the future, paste the relevant html and css in your question and in a Fiddle or Bin.

Change the inline-block to block:

```
/* Outline Outward */
.outline-outward {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Cool. Please select this as the answer.